# Edit Label on Order Totals Block on Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, labels

I have installed a module called "Magentix" on my site.
I want to edit the Label on the Order:
[image]

What would be the path and file? I couldn't find it. 
Thanks

Comment: Is it in admin area?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri yes. Sales > Order > Order Transaction

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be changing it from 'translator`.

Go to `app/locale/Your_Locale/Mage_Sales.csv` and find `Delivery Fee/Shipping Fee` and change to anything that you want.

For example like this:

```
"Delivery Fee/Shipping Fee" "Your new text"
```

**If translation is done by your extension then find the translation file of that extension and do changes there.**

PS: if you cannot find `Delivery Fee/Shipping Fee` then just add `"Delivery Fee/Shipping Fee" "Your new text"`.

**IF you wish to change from php file**

The file responsible for this is `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals.php` and function is `_initTotals()`.

I suggest you to extend this function in your local and then do the changes, **avoid changing core file.**

Comment: @AdarashKhatri there is no text being added on the "Translator". Then how am I suppose to edit it?

Comment: simply add that line, will work.

Comment: but wish to add a dynamic coding for it. I just need to edit wih in a php file.

Comment: Check my update.